# C++20 concepts не работает

Tags: c++, c++17, std, c++20, concept

Пишу в `Visual studio 19`.

Установил стандарт языка `с++20`

Вот код из лекции:

```
template<typename T>
concept Incrementable = requires(T t)
{
    {++t}->T&;
};
```

`Visual studio` ругается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что на этом месте должен быть `type-constraint`, а не тип. Надо использовать или `std::same_as`, или `std::convertible_to`, в зависимости от необходимого поведения.

Дока [Compound Requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints).

Почему так сделано сказано [в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170606/13970074): иначе была бы неоднозначная трактовка. Выражение `++t` преобразуемо в `T&` или его тип в точности равен `T&`?

Comment: в namespace std нету `convertiable_to`. Пробовал подключить заголовок <concepts>. Не помогло

Comment: @Данил вы неправильно написали, вот https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to

Comment: я обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Данил https://godbolt.org/z/ja3Y94

Comment: Ну там подключается, а у меня нет(

Comment: @Данил так сравните внимательно, у вас на скрине `;` нет, например

Comment: поставил, ошибка осталась

Comment: @Данил вы скопировали код по ссылке и вам всё равно выдаёт ошибку? Если да, то какую?

Comment: namespace "std" не содержит члена "convertible_to"

Comment: @Данил проверьте поддержку в вашей версии [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019#note_20), уберите `using namespace std;` и другой код, которого нет по ссылке, если ещё этого не сделали